# how to get client IP in JavaScript , angularjs2 and restrict access to other users.

Tags: angular, ip, client

how  to get **client IP** in JavaScript , **angularjs2** and restrict access to other users.

Comment: Add what you tried

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Http get request can help you**

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

getIp(): Promise<Hero[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
         })
         .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
  console.error('An error occurred', error); 
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

**your response will be like this**

```
{
   "ip": "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx",
   "city": "Chennai",
   "region": "Tamil Nadu",
   "country": "IN",
   "loc": "10.0833,79.2833",
   "org": "AS4755 TATA COMM MAINTAINER"
}
```